# Nexus 7 Trusted Execution Environment for Storing Vital Information

Tags: java, android, security, nexus-7

I researched about samsung galaxy s3 having the mobicore as part of its TEE(Trusted Execution Environment), I was wondering if there is also a similar mobicore-like for Nexus 7 , where there is a **secure world** that my app running nexus 7 use for security purposes.

Please see link http://www.sensepost.com//blogstatic/2013/06/mobicore.png

Comment: The Cortex A9 processors in the Tegra 3 chipset that the Nexus 7 uses support ARM Trustzone, however I don't know whether this is exposed within the system.

Comment: hmm.. I guess i need to do more research.. but i'll set this one aside, thanks